Remote post GET request urlencoding
I am using Drupal Webform and am writing a custom webform handler.  I do not have control over the endpoint that I am submitting to.  The requirement is that it is a GET Request and the url is with parameter values + encoded rather than % encoded.  So for example instead of https://example.edu/myendpoint?key1=value1&key2=value2a%20value2b it should be encoded as https://example.edu/myendpoint?key1=value1&key2=value2a+value2b.  The GET request url and options are passed to Drupal’s buildQuery function by Webform which returns the percent encoded string.  Does anyone know how I can “get” Webform to return the + encoded string instead?

I imagine you'd need to swap out the service which makes the API call, and rewrite the part which does the HTTP request, replacing the Guzzle client (which is RFC 3986 compliant, and thus doesn't support your requirement) with a custom version. The custom version would use urlencode, rather than rawurlencode (the former replaces spaces with + for "historical reasons"). If you have any sway with the API owners, maybe mention that their service doesn't conform to RFC 3986, which it probably should do

(or if the media type is x-www-form-urlencoded, that %20 and + are equivalent, and the HTML spec says both are fine).

Thanks @Clive!  Yes, I had to do the former.  I just didn't know if there was an easier way to accomplish this.  But it makes sense that there isn't, given that it's not RFC compliant.  But I appreciate the response.
